# Can list items have sub-items

Tags: list, custom-list, list-item

I am trying to create a custom list where the list items can have sub-items, and I haven't found a way to do this (which is why I need some help).

What I am working on is a list of the forms my company uses, and some of our forms are built in such a way that there is a parent form with multiple child forms (for example, we have an Add/Remove User form where the first form page links to either the Add or the Remove form). The list is to evaluate the forms to see what is obsolete, and because there are sub-forms I want to be able to show them listed as items under the parent item, exactly like you can have sub-tasks under tasks in a Task List. What I don't want is to just have a column with a value that specifies the parent because that really doesn't help the visual organization of the list and the item relationships.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: wouldn't a grouped view help visualize the relationship?

Comment: A grouped view won't help since most of the items don't have a parent. Only about 20 of the 200 items have a parent that they fall under

Answer (score 4):

An easy way for this is to create Parent items as Folder instead of item. You can create a custom Parent content type inheriting from Folder content type. Inside that Parent items , you can add your sub-items.

Comment: My end goal is to display the items like a task list so that I can see everything in the list and so that list items that fall underneath another item are displayed as indented and directly beneath the "parent." Will this do that or will it just add items inside of a folder/container?

Answer (score 0):

With SP2013 there is the possibility to use the ootb Task List.

The Task List provides the action for creating sub-tasks (additionally you can move, outdent, indent, move up, move down).

Content Types etc. could be adapted to your needs.